# C#: How do I do simple math, with rounding, on integers?

Tags: c#, math, rounding

i want the result of an equation rounded to the nearest integer.
e.g.

```
137 * (3/4) = 103
```

Consider the following incorrect code.

```
int width1 = 4;
int height1 = 3;

int width2 = 137;
int height2 = width2 * (height1 / width1);
```

What is the proper way to perform "integer" math in C#?

Do i really have to do:

```
int height2 = (int)Math.Round(
      (float)width2 * ((float)height1 / (float)width1)
   );
```

Comment: It's sad that after a year i still have to come back to reference this question in order to figure how to do math in C#. In delphi i would just type "137 * 3/4" and it would work. But not C#, C# forces you to pray to the compiler gods before you can do what you want.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As said above, you should do the multiplication before the division.
Anyway you could write your expression with casting only the divisor:

```
int height2 = (int)Math.Round(width2 * (height1 / (float)width1));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int height2 = (width2 * height1) / width1;
```

Comment: This solution only rounds down and will not round up if required. For example if width1 = (width2*height1 + 1), then (width2 * height1)/width1 results in 0, not 1. In other words if the divisor is slightly larger than the dividend, then integer division will produce 0 while floating point division with rounding will produce 1.

Comment: @Catch22 - Yes, that is an excellent point. The version with float conversions is a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

Do multiplication first (as long as they're not likely to overflow) and division second.

3/4 == 0 in integer math (integer math doesn't round on division, it truncates).

If you really need rounding, you have to either work in fixed point, floating point, or play around with the modulus.

Comment: With the benefit of a year of hindsight: can you explain *why* i should do multiplication first?

Comment: Multiplication ends up shifting digits to the left. Division shifts to the right.  If the multiplication doesn't result in overflow, no precision is lost.  Division is highly likely to lose precision since you will lose bits (if you divide by 2, you lose 1 bit, if you divide by 16 you lose 4, etc).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the most elegant way to do this:

```
Math.round(myinteger * 0.75);
```

Using 0.75 instead of 3/4 will implicitly cast it to an double/float and why not use the default functions that are provided for this?

Comment: Math.round(...) returns a double and not an int (so there will be more casting involved) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I will fix the incorrect code by adding zero lines of code:

```
float width1 = 4;
float height1 = 3;

float width2 = 137;
float height2 = width2 * (height1 / width1);
```

You should use floats for variables that can possibly contain decimals. This includes heights calculated from ratios. You can always cast to int later if that is a problem.

Comment: The orginal values are integers and can only contain integers. The question is then how to do math with them.  If i was performing floating-point math i would  have asked that. (actually, not really, since FP math wouldn't have the problem)

Answer (score 1):

Never cast to float, it has even less precision than a 32-bit integer. If you're going to use floating point, always use double instead of float.

Comment: Since i'll be rounding to a 32-bit integer anyway, does it matter than the double has a meaningful digit in the 8th place after the decimal and float does not?

Comment: i.e. is 79.99999999 worse than 79.99999999999

Comment: Yes. 32 bit int is about 9 digits, but 32 bit float is only about 7. And remember: code that occasionally gives a slightly wrong answer is the worst kind of bug, much worse than always getting a completely wrong answer!

Comment: Can you come up with any example where Single math converted to a 32-bit integer gives the wrong answer, where Double math converted to a 32-bit integer is right?

Comment: @IanBoyd: What's 16777216.0f + 1.0f?

Comment: @IanBoyd: Have you tried it?  Unless you're using a language which promotes `float` to `double`, 16777216.0f+1.0f yields 16777216.0f, since there are no `float` values between 16777216.0f and 16777218.0f.

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled upon this question. Aaron's answer seems almost right to me. But I'm very sure you need to specify midpointrounding if your problem is a "real world" problem. So my answer, based on Aaron's code, is

```
int height2 = (int)Math.Round(width2 * (height1 / (float)width1),MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

To see the difference run that code in console

```
    Console.WriteLine((int)Math.Round(0.5));
    Console.WriteLine((int)Math.Round(1.5));
    Console.WriteLine((int)Math.Round(2.5));
    Console.WriteLine((int)Math.Round(3.5));
    Console.WriteLine((int)Math.Round(0.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    Console.WriteLine((int)Math.Round(1.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    Console.WriteLine((int)Math.Round(2.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    Console.WriteLine((int)Math.Round(3.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    Console.ReadLine();
```

For details you may look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article.

Answer (score 1):

Six years (rounded) later, here's my contribution - a little trick I learned long ago, and am surprised that nobody else has mentioned here.

The idea is to do rounding by adding half of the divisor to the numerator before doing the division.

```
    int height2 = (width2 * height1 + width1 / 2) / width1;
```

In reality I wouldn't necessarily recommend doing that in cases, like the OP's, where the divisor is a variable. Instead it may be better to use Math.Round(), as it's much easier to understand.

But in cases where the divisor is a constant I do use this trick. So instead of

```
    int height2 = width2 * height1 / 4;  // No rounding
```

I'd use

```
    int height2 = (width2 * height1 + 2) / 4;
```

Here's a more typical example

```
  private static Size ResizeWithPercentage(Size oldSize, int resizePercentage)
  {
     return new Size((oldSize.Width * resizePercentage + 50) / 100, 
                     (oldSize.Height * resizePercentage + 50) / 100);
  }
```

Another possibility is to combine this trick with the idea mentioned by dongilmore and supercat that instead of having a division by two specified or implied, you can multiply both the numerator and denominator by two.

```
    int height2 = (width2 * height1 * 2 + width1) / (width1 * 2);
```

This gives better answers in cases where the divisor is, or may be, an odd number.

Answer (score 0):

The elaborate on Jeffery's message, since you generally a better chance of truncated needed decimals than you have of overflowing a 32-bit integer (and because multiplication & division is commutative), you should generally do multiplication before division.

Answer (score 0):

```
int height2 = ((width2 * height1 * 10) + 5) / (width1 * 10);
```

Prior to any integer division, check to make certain the divisor is not zero.
Also note this assumes positive quotient. If negative, roundoff needs to be -5, not +5.

Comment: doesn't help.  still gets 102

Comment: Should be "int height2 = ((width2 * height1 * 10) + width1 * 5) / (width1 * 10);"

Answer (score 0):

Convert's conversions always round so:

```
int height2 = Convert.ToInt32(width2 * height1 / (double)width1);
```

Answer (score 0):

A reasonably effective approach if the final division will be by an even number and the result will always be positive is to divide by half that value, add one, and divide by two.  If the result may be negative, you should if possible add an amount that will make everything be positive, do the computation, and then subtract a corresponding amount afterward.

If the final division will be by an odd number, multiply both numerator and denominator by 2, then proceed as above.  For example, to compute a*5/7, rounded, compute `(a*10+1)>>1`.  The one thing to watch out for is that you may need to extend your values to a larger numeric type to avoid overflow or, if that isn't possible, subdivide the division into pieces.  For example, to compute a*14/15, you might compute ((a*4/3*7)/5+1)/2.  That computation may still overflow if a is too big, but the allowable range will be three times as big as if it was evaluated without doing the divide by 3 before the other division.  Note that subdividing the operation will make the rounding slightly less precise, but still close enough for many purposes.

Comment: There's something wrong with your first example, you're missing the division by 7. And your very first sentence says something different from what you're doing in all of your examples, as far as I can understand it.

Comment: @RenniePet: Is that better?